# How to add user last login date in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: c#, xml, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I created a custom attribute in Azure AD B2C in TrustFrameforkExtensions.xml

Add ClaimType

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_LastLogin">
    <DisplayName>extension_LastLogin</DisplayName>
    <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="lastLogin"/>
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>
```

Add ClaimsTransformation

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GetLastLoginDateTime" TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime">
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_LastLogin" TransformationClaimType="currentDateTime"/>
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Add in TechnicalPrifile this

```
<InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLastLoginDateTime" />
</InputClaimsTransformations>
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_LastLogin" />
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_LastLogin" />
</OutputClaims>
```

Also added Claims to RelyingParty (SignUp\LogIn and others.)

This is not the first field which I`ve added, but the only problem with this.
But when I try to get the attribute value using .Net SDK, there is no such field.

This field exists in claims in AuthenticationContext, But not exists in Graph API response

Comment: You haven't added it to the JWT issuer element I think.

Comment: Could you please tell how to do it? I think that this string add attr to JWT

`<Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="lastLogin"/>`

Comment: No. That defines what the property will be in JWT if it is put there. There is a separate place where you define claims to put in token.